# Deploy play 2.2.1 application to openshift

Tags: git, deployment, playframework, playframework-2.0, openshift

I have developed an application in play 2.2.1.

I have installed rhc from openshift and I have created with rhc:

```
rhc app create <projectName> -t diy-0.1 --no-git -l <email Adresse>
```

Then I changed into the project folder and used:

```
git init 

git remote add origin ssh://UUID@test-testpage.rhcloud.com
/~/git/testpage.git/

git pull -s recursive -X theirs origin master
```

However, here I am stuck, because I get from git:

```
$ git pull -s recursive -X theirs origin master
ssh: connect to host  port 22: Bad file number
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I have to say that I am deploying from a windows 7 machine and do not use rhc and git in the same terminal. However, I can create an application, but cannot `pull` ;P What am I doing wrong? What would be another way to deploy my applicaiton to openshift?

I really would appreciate your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first guesses would be an issue with your git url or an ssh key issue.  Your example above has a slight problem but I doubt that was the problem with the url you tried:

```
ssh://UUID@test-testpage.rhcloud.com
```

should be

```
ssh://UUID@testpage-test.rhcloud.com
```

where testpage is your app name and test is your namespace.  You can run rhc domain show to see for sure what you url should be.

Given the error message, I don't think your issue is ssh keys but you can run rhc setup to make sure your key is in place.  Also try running:

```
ssh UUID@testpage-test.rhcloud.com
```

from the same terminal running git if that's possible.

Also note you can also do this instead of init/remote add/pull:

```
git clone ssh://UUID@testpage-test.rhcloud.com/~/git/testpage.git/
```